# Get currently active 'simpletest' user during test

Tags: 7, testing

How do you retrieve the current 'simpletest' user during a simpletest.

During a simpletest is the $user GLOBAL from the test environment or the live environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the test method?

No idea what in $GLOBALS['user'] is, but you certainly can't rely on it. You are never "logged in" in that context, you are only logged in when doing requests with drupalGet()/drupalPost().

If you used [drupalLogin()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--simpletest--drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalWebTestCase%3a%3adrupalLogin/7), you can look for $this->loggedInUser. If not, then it's not possible, other than maybe doing a GET to /user and then trying to get the username from title.

Inside a page callback, $GLOBALS['user'] is the current user, just like you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you @Berdir. $this->loggedInUser and user_load did the trick and makes for a way cleaner test class.